# Pointing to this object vba syntax

Tags: vba, object, this

I have two class modules.  Say class1 and class2.  I want to set one of class2's properties to be class1 from within class 1.  I know in java you can do something like

```
Class1{
    Set Class2Object= This 

}
Class2{
Declare Property as Class1
}
```

Does vba have an equivalent to "This" from java?  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you should take advantage of [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for this and some other of questions you asked.

Answer (score 0):

in `VBA` you use `Me` instead of `this`

by the way in `VBA` you use `Dim` not `Declare`

and you don't have `{` and `}` you simply end it with `End Class`so your code should look like this

```
Public Class1

Set Class2.Propertyname = Me

End Class

Public Class2

Dim Propertyname as Class1

End Class
```

hope this helps

Comment: glad i could help as you were happy with the answer please accept it as shown here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work as this lets the community know that your problem has been solved